# I can't scroll pass the navigation bar when I fix it to the top of the viewport/webpage in CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, navbar

After I fix the navigation bar to the top of the viewport, I can scroll, but I can't scroll past the header.  I don't scroll down through the body.

I can't scroll when I use the codes below in CSS.  When I take it away, I can scroll down through the viewport/webpage again.

```
#nav-bar {position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 675px;}
```

or

```
nav {display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: lightgreen; 
font-family: sans-serif;
color: red; 
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 675px;
  }
```

When I fix the navigation bar to the top of the viewport, I want to srcoll through the whole webpage and not get stuck in the header section.

Comment: what does _"can't scroll past the header"_ mean? Can you provide a working example?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can do this.  But here is the link to get a better understanding.....  https://codepen.io/millsdee42/pen/MRybZJ?editors=1100  Thanks for responding too.

Comment: Well that codepen has invalid HTML markup. The `<header>` is not inside the `<body>` tag. **All** content should be inside the `<body>` tag. Is this how your HTML is structured?

Comment: @zgood  included the header in the body as you suggested.  And, after I fix the navigator bar to the top of the page, I still can't scroll pass the header.

Comment: everytime I fix the position( ie. {position: fixed;}), I can't scroll pass the header.